# How to fix this shower drain or swap out

Tags: bathroom, shower, tile

New shower, tiler messed up the shower drain for this Schluter tile able drain. Contractor said he will fix but I want to make sure he doesn’t cut corners.
Should we attempt again & if so can we pop some tiles out around the drain or should I just replace with a regular drain gate from Schluter?

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have a conversation with your contractor, ask him what he's planning on doing. If it's a repair instead of replace, get it _in writing_ that he'll do a full replacement if you're not satisfied with the repair. Then let him go to town.